# Getting Selenium "Element not clickable" issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click the element. When I am executing my test in a computer it runs perfectly, but when I am executing my test in a laptop it is failing. Getting error Element not clickable. I have tried to use different wait times as well. Have no idea where is issue. This is what I am using :

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='startExam()']"))).click;

Action action=new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(ele).perform();
action.movetoElemet(ele).click().perform.
```

This what I have in inspect console:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-if="!proctoredSession" ng-click="startExam()" ng-dissabled="!isExamContentLoaded">Start Exam</button>==$0
```

Comment: This what I have in a inspect console:
<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-if="!proctoredSession" ng-click="startExam()" ng-dissabled="!isExamContentLoaded">Start Exam</button>==$0

Comment: What is the screen size of your desktop and laptop ?

Comment: 1920*1080 pixel resolution

Comment: and laptop 1366*768 they shoul be same ?

Comment: It all depends, Selenium is designed to interact with elements as we interact with them , so in laptop if the screen size is small you may need to scroll down or some actions you will have to perform to let the element visible in screen and scope.

Comment: would be nice if you can attach screen shot of how locator and screen looks in computer and laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[ng-click='startExam()']"));
```

or

```
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button[ng-click='startExam()']")));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",button);
button.click();
```

Comment: I made mistake, forgot to add element. Check it again

Comment: still not clickable

Comment: Replace `visibilityOfElementLocated` with `elementToBeClickable`. Also check if button is enable `System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[ng-click='startExam()']")).isEnabled());`. Did you try first code with click using javascript?

Comment: it clicked and failed after clicking.Element is not clickable ,isEnabled is true

Comment: after click what do you with button?

Comment: again clicking on End Exam btn

Comment: Click with `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[ng-click='startExam()']"));` every time. Share your code.

Comment: I did exactly  the same as your code .still not clickable error

Comment: @alex : Is the element visible in screen when you run it through selenium ? Are you able to physically see the element when script runs ?

Comment: Maybe you have loading element that overlay button from click. Debug and check when it clicks successfully. Also try `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button, 1, 1).click().build().perform();`

Comment: how it is clicking by action class,but my problem is that when I am executing this script through my computer it is passing ,but when it is running on my laptop it is failing

Comment: I did setSize Dimension But still error is not clickable

Comment: Debug is solution

Comment: Check if driver and browser versions same as in working computer:)

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* within your question the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope[ng-click^='startExam']"))).click();
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary ng-scope'][contains(.,'Start Exam')]"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You may update your existing code as following:

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
Action action=new Actions(driver);

WebElement temp = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='startExam()']")));
action.moveToElement(temp).click().perform();
```